# Separation of one list into 2 list by one key

Tags: c#

Is there any other way to write this separation?

```
public Parent Method()
{
        Parent parent = new Parent { ChildA= new List<Child>(),
                                     ChildB= new List<Child>()};

        List<Child> allChildren = _manager.GetChildren();

        foreach (Child child in allChildren)
        {
            if (child.Age > 5)
            {
                parent.ChildA.Add(child);
            }
            else
            {
                parent.ChildB.Add(child);
            }
        }
             return orderParents;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like pseudo code, which is off topic.  ChildA and ChildB are strange names for a collection of children whose age is >5 or <=5.  `orderParents` which is being returned doesn't appear to exist...

Comment: @forsvarir the original code is exactly same that you told.I changed the variable names to be clear. My problem is parent.ChildB.Add(child); parent.ChildA.Add(child); lines look the same I need to refactor it

Comment: What is the use-case for this? How many parents are there in your application? Will all of them have two lists of children? Why is the method called `Method`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There actually is...

You can first group the children by `Age > 5` and then turn the groups into lists:

```
var grouppedChildren = children.GroupBy(x => x.Age > 5);
var parent = new Parent
{
    ChildA = grouppedChildren.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key)?.ToList(),
    ChildB = grouppedChildren.SingleOrDefault(g => !g.Key)?.ToList(),
}
```

---

## OCP

The original soultion violates the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). What if you have more categories later? You would need to not only modify the `Parent` class but other methods categorizing children by age.

I suggest you let the `Parent` class store all children

```
class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }    
}
```

and create extensions to extract the ones you need.

First by creating a general all purpose method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Child> BetweenOrEqual(this IEnumerable<Child> children, int min, int max) 
{
    return children.Where(x => x.Age >= min && x.Age <= max);
}
```

so you can do:

```
var result1 = parent.Children.BetweenOrEqual(6,12);
var result2 = parent.Children.BetweenOrEqual(0,5);
```

Then you can use this extension to add more specialized cases that implement  your particular logic:

```
public static IEnumerable<Child> Young(this IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    children.BetweenOrEqual(0, 5);
}
```

and

```
public static IEnumerable<Child> Older(this IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    children.BetweenOrEqual(6, 12);
}
```

so finally you'll have:

```
var young = parent.Children.Young();
var older = parent.Children.Older();
```

---

You didn't add the *performance* tag so I assumed enumerating the children collection wont't noticable. Should you work with a database and have many thousands items then creating categories an groupping the results by various ages might have a better performance. For a few hundred items it doesn't matter and premature optimization should be avoided.

Comment: best solution, I applied open/closed principle now

Answer (score 3):

I presume that line fetches data from somewhere.

```
List<Child> allChildren = _manager.GetChildren();
```

And then you decide what to do with a Child.

I would rather take responsibility to decide which collection that specific Child belongs to be put inside Parent itself.

You can introduce a new method in Parent to accept new Childs. And inside that method Parent itself can decide what's right for kid. Think of it as you have your little brothers coming in for overnight and you need to decide which one sleeps in which room, not the driver rides them to you.

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> LittleOnes { get; }
    public List<Child> BigBoys { get; }

    public void AddChild(Child newOne)
    {
        // Some logic here.
        if (newOne.Age > 5)
        { 
            BigBoys.Add(newOne); 
        }
    }
}
```